# Switch State Change Does Not Work On The First Click

Tags: android, listview, view

If I change any switch state the `DatabaseReference` doesn't change from the previous value the first time... if I change the same switch state one more time it works perfectly. Here is my code:

```
public sigAdapter(Context context, String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
    super(context, R.layout.list, web);
    this.context = context;
    this.web = web;
    this.imageId = imageId;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference1 = database.getReference("data").child(web[position1].replace("/",""));
    databaseReference=databaseReference1.child("Switch");
    ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

    View listItemView = view;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);

        viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        viewHolder.switch1 = (Switch) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.switch_button);

        final ViewHolder finalViewHolder = viewHolder;
        viewHolder.switch1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                position1 = (Integer)v.getTag();
                finalViewHolder.switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        DatabaseReference databaseReference1=database.getReference("data").child(web[position1].replace("/",""));
                        DatabaseReference databaseReference2=databaseReference1.child("Switch");
                        if (isChecked){
                            databaseReference2.setValue("On");
                        }else {
                            databaseReference2.setValue("Off");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        listItemView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)listItemView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.switch1.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
    viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

    return listItemView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are setting the `OnCheckedChangeListener` in the `OnClickListener`; so the `onCheckChanged()` method only gets called *after* the first click (not *on* the first click).

Just use an `OnCheckedChangeListener` from the start instead.

```
viewHolder.switch1 = (Switch) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.switch_button);

switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        position1 = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();

        DatabaseReference databaseReference1 = database.getReference("data").child(web[position1].replace("/",""));
        DatabaseReference databaseReference2 = databaseReference1.child("Switch");

        if (isChecked){
            databaseReference2.setValue("On");
        } else {
            databaseReference2.setValue("Off");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but when doing so the "position" stays always on last..  any switch change causes the datareference corresponding the last switch changes..

Comment: @Sayandh You're talking about the `position1` variable? Why do you mean it "stays always on last"? You can get the `tag` from the `buttonView` provided by `onCheckedChanged()` as well.

Comment: Still its same onCheckChanged() method gets called after the 1st click..

Comment: @Sayandh That is not expected. You removed all of the `OnClickListener` code?

Comment: no i didnt.. position1 is getting from OnClickListener but same effect...

Comment: are you there??

Comment: @Sayandh Remove the `OnClickListener`! Get `position1` as I do in the code above.

Comment: @Sayandh In fact, you shouldn't need the `position1` variable at all... why not just use the `position` provided by `getView()`?

Comment: will you please answer this one too??

Comment: i need to save all the switch status in the list view what is the correct method to do it???

Comment: @Sayandh Create a new question, this seems unrelated to the current question.

Comment: i cant create a new questions right now.. I can ask question after 3 days only...